# How to fix error with git config?

Tags: git

`git: 'credential-credential-store' is not a git command. See 'git --help'`

I have tried to remove the whole section of `credential`

`git config --remove-section credential`

But it didn't help. How to fix it? It appears each time I push new changes to the remote

Comment: Open the git config file in an editor with `git config -e` and remove the section by hand.

Comment: Thanks, it, works!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to run

```
git config --global -e
```

This will allow you to remove the conflicting config setting from the global git config.

```
[credential]
helper = winstore
```

Comment: @serhiiminin..if it has helped you, please mark it as a correct answer so it will help others when stuck with same problem